# Is it common for Koreans to say '내일 모레' to mean 'the day after tomorrow'?

Tags: word-usage

I thought '모레' meant 'the day after tomorrow', but today I heard some Koreans saying '내일 모레'. I confirmed with them that they meant 'the day after tomorrow'.

Is this common? Why add the '내일' ?

Comment: i think it just means let's meet sometime in the future, without specifying a date

Comment: @user17915 No Korean would say "내일 모레" to imply sometime in the future. It's "the day after tomorrow" for sure.

Comment: "글피" means "the day after 모레" and Korean people usually say "내일 모래 글피" or "모레 글피". I don't know the reason why exactly, but I guess it's just idiomatic usage. If I hear people say "글피 만나자", I would respond, "Huh?", but if I hear people say "모레 글피 만나자", I would respond "Ah, yes.". I don't think there is any rule on this, but I would say it helps you get the clearer picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Korean. I think it is to put emphasis on the meaning.

*모레 < 내일 모레*

If someone just says "모레 만나자! 모레 뭐할건데?", the word '모레' confuses me.

모레 and 모래(sand) have the same pronunciation.

Answer (score 3):

I am Korean, and I find it very common to say "내일 모레" to mean the day after tomorrow.
I say it almost everytime I need to say the day after tomorrow.
It's not like there's an emphasis or anything here.
It's just habitual.

In the meantime, it is totally fine to say just "모레."
I don't see anything wrong with this either.
It actually doesn't confuse me with 모래(sand) because I would be understanding terms in the context of time.

It's just that I happen to say "내일 모레" without thinking whenever I mean the day after tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

No, 내일 모레 is a not that definitive. It's just like an  English speaker saying "tomorrow or the day after". It means they may do it but are not committing to an exact answer. I may add that 내일 모레 is quick speaking for 내일이나 모레.

If one thinks 모레 and 모래 sound the same, then you need to get a native Korean speaker to say 에 and 애 for you you can listen carefully. They are not the same.

Comment: 내일 모레 is "the day after tomorrow", definitively.